# Website behaving differently in Google App engine than in localhost - urlmapping

Tags: google-app-engine, web.xml, url-mapping, java-server

I was trying to do some stuffs with the tQueryCar : http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2012/05/21/sport-car-in-webgl/

I created a new app engine project and do the required stuffs and this webGL car was running fine on localhost. But when I uploaded it to app engine I'm getting some error in the firebug console. Everything is rendered except the car. This is the app engine url :
http://tquerycar.appspot.com

I couldn't figure what actually is happening. Everything is working fine on localhost.

Edit :
Ok. I have figured what's wrong is happening. My tQueryCar HTML code is making GET request to this address : `http://tquerycar.appspot.com/plugins/car//examples/obj/veyron/parts/veyron_body_bin.js`. But in my web.xml I've mapped the url `/` to my `CarServlet` class which in turn always output my `index.html` file. So I just want to ask now how to map URL in Java Servlet as stuffs work in a normal apache server. That's why site works fine on apache server running on localhost.

P.S. I personally don't know much about java servlet.

Comment: 'some error'? What error?

Comment: I've provided the app engine URL. You can open it in your web browser and see the error.

Comment: People who don't want to share their email address with you might want to help, but your choice.

Comment: means  ?
What other information do you want ?

Comment: I've updated the question. Please answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the main problem was all the urls were mapped to `CarServlet` class which was outputting my index.html in response. So I created a `CommonServlet` class to map all other URLs :

```
package in.omerjerk.tquerycar;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CommonServlet extends HttpServlet  {
 @Override
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
   throws ServletException, IOException {
  ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
  String path=req.getRequestURI().substring(req.getContextPath().length()+1, req.getRequestURI().length());
     String filename = sc.getRealPath(path);

     // Get the MIME type of the image
     String mimeType = sc.getMimeType(filename);
     if (mimeType == null) {
         sc.log("Could not get MIME type of "+filename);
         resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
         return;
     }
     // Set content type
     resp.setContentType(mimeType);

     // Set content size
     File file = new File(filename);
     resp.setContentLength((int)file.length());

     // Open the file and output streams
     FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
     OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();

     // Copy the contents of the file to the output stream
     byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
     int count = 0;
     while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
         out.write(buf, 0, count);
     }
     in.close();
     out.close();
 }
}
```

And mapped `/car` to `CarServlet` and `/` to `CommonServlet`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo in two of the resource urls:

http://tquerycar.appspot.com/plugins/car//examples/obj/veyron/parts/veyron_wheel_bin.js
http://tquerycar.appspot.com/plugins/car//examples/obj/veyron/parts/veyron_body_bin.js

These aren't loading in production because of the double forward slash.  Specifically, the tQuery.Car.baseUrl in tquery.car.js has a trailing forward slash that probably shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thanks for you hint. 
I've updated the question. Please answer it.